# A question about multivariable calculus and optimization

Tags: real-analysis, global-optimization, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f(x) :\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $f(x)\geqslant 0\; \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, and has a set of extremum points at $x_{j}$.
Consider the integral :
$$\int_{\bar{x}}^{g_{c}(\bar{x})}f(x)dx=c$$
where c is a constant, and $g_{c}(\bar{x})$ is a function of $\bar{x}$, that depends on our choice of c. intuitively, we have that :
$$x_{j}\in[\bar{x_{j}},g_{c}(\bar{x_{j}})]$$ for which the quantity $g_{c}(\bar{x})-\bar{x}$ is maximum or minimum. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, this condition is equivalent to  $f(g_{c}(\bar{x_{j}}))=f(\bar{x_{j}})$. In other words, every $x_{j}$ lies in a set, whose boundary is a level set of $f(x)$. In order to solve for $x_{j}$, one finds the anti-derivative of $f(x)$ :
$$F(x)=\int f(x)dx$$
and then takes the limit $c\rightarrow 0$. or $F(g_{0}(\bar{x_{j}}))=F(\bar{x_{j}})$. Together with $f(g_{0}(\bar{x_{j}}))=f(\bar{x_{j}})$, we can solve for $x_{j}$

My question, how does this generalize to the case of functions in many variables ? for instance, in the case of $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ one expects that $(x,y)_{j} \in \Gamma_{f}$. where $\partial\Gamma_{f}$ is a level set of $f(x,y)$. Also, the quantity to be maximized (or minimized) is 
$$\int_{\Gamma_{f}}dx dy$$ 
How to formalize this intuition rigorously ?

Comment: what is g here?

Comment: Maybe you want to maximize the integral of f over a suitable class of domains, and conclude that the maximizing domain must contain a critical point of f?

Comment: g is a function of $\bar{x}$

Comment: why the vote down ?

Comment: @PietroMajer ... that's exactly my intuition, except that i want to maximize or minimize the integral, depending on whether i am looking for a minima (in which case the integral should be maximized), or a maxima (in which case the integral should be minimized). But i am not sure that the intuition generalizes nicely to the case of functions in many variables. Hence, the question.

Comment: @PietroMajer ... On a second though, the integral of f on suitable class of domains is to be kept constant, the domain itself is to be maximized or minimized (using a suitable measure of size, in the case of a function in a single variable the measure is length, in the case of the second example in my post the measure is area.)